# What's the difference with childprocess.fork between cluster.fork

Tags: node.js

Simple question: What's the difference with child_process.fork between cluster.fork

detail:

1. can I pass arguments to cluster.fork
2. can I listen on same port or unixsock for ChildProcess create by child_process.fork

Comment: cluster.fork makes me laugh and childprocess.fork does not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the docs: [`child_process.fork`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) vs [`cluster.fork`](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_fork).

> The difference between `cluster.fork()` and `child_process.fork()` is simply that cluster allows TCP servers to be shared between workers. `cluster.fork` is implemented on top of `child_process.fork`.

http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

---

> 1. can I pass arguments to cluster.fork

Not according to the docs, and:

```
> var cluster = require('cluster')
undefined
> cluster
{ isWorker: false,
  isMaster: true,
  fork: [Function],
  _startWorker: [Function],
  _getServer: [Function] }
> cluster.fork.length
0
```

(a [function's `length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) is its number of formal parameters). Use [message passing](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle) instead.

> 2. can I listen on same port or unixsock for ChildProcess create by child_process.fork

Presumably yes, since `cluster.fork` is implemented on top of `child_process.fork`. However, there is a *reason* that `cluster.fork` already exists, if you want to listen on the same port.